# How to find the bounded area by a curve

Tags: calculus, integration, area

How to find the area bounded by $(a^2x^2+b^2y^2)^2=a^3x^3-3ab^2xy^2$ in terms of positive constant $a$ and $b$.

Is it using polar coordinates to find out the area? I have no idea to do this question. Can anyone give me any ideas or the answer of this question?

Comment: try substitution $u=ax$ and $v=bx$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja after substitution $u=ax$ and $v=by$, do I need to use polar coordinates?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Also, the most confused part of me is finding the boundaries of the curve.

Comment: I will try with this substitution: $$x=\frac{\rho \cos \varphi}{a}, y=\frac{\rho \sin \varphi}{b}, J=\frac{\rho}{ab}.$$

Apply substitution: $$(\rho^2)^2=\rho^3\cos^3\varphi - 3\rho^3\cos \varphi \sin^2\varphi  \iff \rho = \cos \varphi(\cos^2\varphi-3\sin^2\varphi)$$

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak that's it!